# OAuthException: Error validating access token

Tags: iphone, xcode, fbconnect

I am doing login using facebook section of my iphone app. I want to send the access token to the server side. Now i am facing this problem. I can login successfully with a new account, but when I log out and then again log in, I am getting the error response like this:

> error = "OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session does
>   not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed
>   the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has
>   changed the session for security reasons.

Kindly give some suggestions to solve this issue.

logout method:

```
-(void)logoutFb{
     [_facebook logout:self];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBAcessToken"]
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpDate"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Earlier i was asking for these permissions only:

`publish_stream`,`read_stream`,`offline_access` Now I added email & user_birthday also.

Did some corrections in the webservice too.

Comment: Why did adding email and user_birthday fix this ?